# Why Thumbs.db File create in My Project drawable Folder?

Tags: android

Why `Thumbs.db` file generated in my drawable folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blame Windows: it always creates such files when you browse the folder in Explorer. You can delete it without risk.

Comment: macos creates even more trash

Answer (score 0):

Thumbs.db is a file which holds miniatures of your images for quick preview. You can delete it whithout side effects.